# rsi value of ongoing week is missing in series

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

The pine script below will set a label over every weekly candle (if set to candle resolution weekly). The last week is missing. How could I add that current RSI weekly value? Any clue?

```
strategy("RSI Strategy", overlay=true, initial_capital = 1000, default_qty_value= 100, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity)
  

btcWeekly = security("BINANCE:BTCUSDT", "W", close) // 240 Minutes
rsi_w = rsi(btcWeekly, 14)

plotchar(rsi_w, "Weekly RSI Value", "", location = location.top)


label.new(bar_index, high, tostring(rsi_w, "#.#"), yloc = yloc.abovebar, color = color.red, style = label.style_label_down)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to pinescript strategy [execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html?highlight=calc_on_every_tick#execution-model) the strategies ignore the real-time bar and execute only on confirmed historical bars. To force the strategy to execute on real-time bar (current weekly candle in your example) add calc_on_every_tick argument as is shown in the example below:

```
//@version=4
strategy("RSI Strategy", overlay=true, initial_capital = 1000, default_qty_value= 100, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, calc_on_every_tick = true)
...
```

[image]
[image]